# JSON.parse is giving me an error when I parse a string

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

When I run

```js
JSON.parse(`{name: 'test'}`);
```

I get an error. I'm just trying to parse a string and return it as JSON.

Comment: It should be a valid JSON ``{"name": "test"}``. Notice the double quotes in key and value

Comment: That string is **not** valid JSON.

Comment: Closely related: [simple JSON Parse error, not sure what went wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33707259/4642212).

Answer (score 5):

That isn't valid JSON. Properties are named with double quotes and strings are in double quotes.

```js
console.log(JSON.parse(`{"name": "test"}`));
```

You can read about JSON here: https://www.json.org/json-en.html

Comment: Ok. Thanks. So all JSON properties and names need double qoutes.

Comment: @Lukas not all values do. strings do.

Comment: @DanielA.White All property names are strings though